# How to display a modal (material UI) in a case of an error?

Tags: node.js, typescript, material-ui, alert

I'm having trouble in displaying an error message recently, I'm trying to open a modal whenever there is an error but I'm having trouble with the action, I tried to put it as an error boundary, but with no successes, Currently, I have the modal in the homepage element, but, unfortunately, handleOpen is not working, if anybody can format the code so it will work, and explain to me why it didn't in the first place, it would be wonderful for my progress as a developer

Code:

```
// modal defining
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  // modal closing
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  }

  // modal opening
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  }

  //file data being saved
  const [fileData, setFileData] = useState<any>();

  // first checks if the columns have names, then checks if they are containing id and name
  const handleFileData = (data: Array<any>) => {
    for (let index = 0; index < data[0].length; index++) {
      if (data[0][index] == null) { return (HOMEPAGE) }
    }
    for (let index = 0; index < data[0].length; index++) {
      if (data[0][index].includes("id"), data[0][index].includes("name")) { setFileData(data); }
    }
  }

  // Routing Element
  const isData = () => {
    if (fileData !== undefined) {
      return <MainPage Data={fileData}></MainPage>
    }
    else {
      return (HOMEPAGE);
    }
  };

  // error message
  const ModalComp = (
    <Modal
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
      aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
      aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
    >
      <Box className='Modal'>
        <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
         problem  </Typography>
        <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
          alert
          <br /> <br />
        alert </Typography>
      </Box>
    </Modal>
  );

  // Home Page Element
  const HOMEPAGE = (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className='H1'>Interface</h1>
      <InputPart handleFileData={handleFileData}></InputPart>
      {ModalComp}
    </div>
  );

  //Browser Router.
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={HOMEPAGE}></Route>
        <Route path="/main" element={isData()}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
} 

export default App;
```

I cant find a way to open the modal when there is an error, if you can tell where, please let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: I Tried also, To put another IF, but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Initially in your state you define the `open` as `false` here:
`const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);`
and in your modal you have the open as `open={open}` which is false so the modal is not showing.
So when you want to trigger the error and show the modal you have to call the function `handleOpen` which will set the state of the modal to true, it will force the modal to re-render because it's state changed and the property `open={open}` will become true, showing you the modal.

At your code seems you are not calling the `handleOpen` anywhere, you are just trying to render the `Homepage`

Comment: Well, I know that, but, and there is a big but in here, i can't call the function HandleOpen for someReason, No matter what i try.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox with a working example? Using your code I was able to open it. For example you can try to have a button that calls the function with "onClick={handleOpen}" . Also does the explanation in the answer makes sense?